# try catch like Java in swift

Tags: swift, exception

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
  try {
     num1 = 0;
     num2 = 62 / num1;
     num3 = num3/2;

  }
  catch (ArithmeticException e) { 
     /* This block will only execute if any Arithmetic exception 
      * occurs in try block
      */
  }
```

But in Swift I have to use:

```
do {
    let sandwich = try makeMeSandwich(kitchen)
    let sandwich2 = try makeMeSandwich(kitchen2)
    try abc(kitchen2) // no return type
    print("i eat it \(sandwich)")
} catch {
    print("Not me error")
}
```

I have to specify `try` for every check. Is there something I can do just like in Java for the whole method?

If no return type method like

```
try abc(kitchen2)
```

it shows me the below warning:

> No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression

and in a `catch` block:

> 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

Comment: You can't just add a statement block like in Java?

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the Swift exception [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html). The only similar example I see has two calls in the `do` block, and both of them are marked with `try`.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. You're already 'wrapping' your code with `do`, and you need to specify `try` for every line that may throw an exception, that's just the way it is. And honestly, I love this because you can easily see what function can throw an exception.

Comment: @James - Yep, I think you got his question right. Just to clarify, though, we're not throwing "exceptions" in Swift. We're throwing errors. It might sound pedantic to dwell on that distinction, but this is actually the root of the issue, namely why Swift needs `try`. The syntactic similarities between other languages' exception handling and Swift's error handling is the root of the confusion. We're we're not dealing with generalized exception catching mechanism, but a very specific feature where the language can only `catch` errors thrown in a `try` statement within a `do` block.

Comment: @James I agree to it but, if there is no return type to try method it shows me warning as I mentioned in edit.

Comment: @Rob No worries, thanks for clarifying the distinction!